# adjustsFontSizeToFit in react native navigation header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Trying to use adjustsFontSizeToFit in the navigation header.
The rest of the styles work.
Am I writing it wrong?

```
navigation.setOptions({
      title: headerTitle,
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontFamily: "Quicksand_500Medium",
        color: "#faf2c4",
        fontSize: 15,
        adjustsFontSizeToFit: true,
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adjustsFontSizeToFit` is not a style property but a parameter that you can apply to `Text` components. If you really want to use this parameter, you have to use a custom title component with the `headerTitle` option. For example :

```
navigation.setOptions({
  headerTitle: () => (
    <Text
      adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}
      style={{
       fontFamily: "Quicksand_500Medium",
       color: "#faf2c4",
       fontSize: 15,
       }}
     />
    {headerTitle}
    </Text>
  )
})
```